# How to serve an IIS Application from a different IIS server?

Tags: iis-7, web-application, folder-redirection

I have a situation where I had an application (IIS7) moved from Server A to Server B.

Prior to the move, the request: www.company.com/Scripts/this.dll was served from an application that resided on Server A.

Server A has my routing and all IP routed to it from the internet, and is my IIS that servers other web requests. (www.company.com)

Is it possible that when someone will ask for the application, I can server it from Server B? but still have the same URL remaining?
Can I do it without playing/changing ports?

E.G.
www.company.com/Scripts/this.dll

The folder /Scripts (and the contained dll) are located on Server B (that is running perfectly, but only can be accessed Internally via the LAN.

Comment: What about HTTP redirection? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I cant - I don't want to open Server B to the internet (if not needed).